# How can I define available values for code completion of a string property in C# in a way that MongoDB.BsonSerializer will understand?

Tags: c#, mongodb, intellisense, code-completion

The main purpose is to show intellisense when setting the property.  It would be great if I could do it via an attribute like the image below.

The property should remain a string(not enum or struct) so that Mongo's BsonSerializer can serialize it properly. Here is an example of what it might look like:

[image]

To help other developers on the team know possible (but not exlusive) values they can use for the Type field Code Completion should display values that can be used as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I have modified the Title to a question.

Comment: It is stil not explaining what it is you are looking for. Something with intelligence showing up, well this is done by proper documenting your code. You want something with custom attributes but I have now idea how this should all fit together..

Comment: I have completely re-formatted the question.  If it does not make sense or the if I have made grammar mistakes please feel free to point them out and I will adjust them.  I would appreciate more information on why the question was downvoted.  If it is a bad question feel free to point that out and I will remove the question from stackoverflow.  I have been trying to solve this issue for the last 3 hours and I am willing to take the hit to my reputation to solve the problem.

Comment: @Aldert thank you for the feedback.  I have added a screenshot of the desired result.  Does this explain what I am looking for clearly enough?

Comment: Yes, i start to get it. I do not have an answer for you. Maybe someone else van help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited) I was able to solve this by creating my own type

```
public class SkinType:StringType<SkinType>
{
    public SkinType(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public SkinType()
    {

    }
    public static implicit operator string(SkinType d)
    {
        return d.Value;

    }
    public static implicit operator SkinType(string d)
    {
        return  new SkinType(d);
    }

    public const string StringValue = nameof(StringValue);
    public const string Color = nameof(Color);
}
```

Now I get intellisense for my Type property and Mongo knows how to serialize it.

Here is how I use it:

```
    public class Skin : ServiceMongoIdentity
{

     //removed some properties for brevity.
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    [BsonDefaultValue(SkinType.StringValue)]
    public SkinType Type { get; set; } = SkinType.StringValue;

}
```

Here is how the StringType base class is defined.  I had to make Value public because Generics cannot have constructors with parameters

```
 public abstract  class StringType<T> where T :StringType<T>,new()
{
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string Value;
    public T FromString(string d)
    {
        return  new T
        {
            Value = d
        };

    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj?.ToString() == Value;

    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {

        return Value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I had to make my own BsonSerializer and JsonConverter.  If anyone is interested I can share.